# Select substring of retrieved value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following table:

```
MyValue
--------------------
123
122_DELETED
45670
42425
43_NO_VIEW
4365463_CORRUPT
53
4335_NO_VIEW_ALLOWED
```

I'm trying to get only the numbers returned. In other words: string everything after the first underscore (`_`):

```
select
  left(MyValue, charindex(('_', MyValue)-1)
from
  DB.Table
```

However, this returns the error `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.` I believe this is because the value is `NULL` in case the current value has no underscore (for instance, `123`).

How can I account for this exception? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: u want integers of string before `_`?

Comment: yes, so `123_BLA_BLA => 123, 45676 => 45676, 12_BLOB => 121` etc :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this!

```
select myval,case when myval like '%[_]%' then
substring(myval,1,patindex('%[_]%',myval)-1) else myval end from t
```

<kbd>##[DEMO USING PATINDEX](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16478/19)</kbd>

<kbd>##[DEMO USING CHARINDEX](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16478/24)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! So elegant. Question: why are you using `patindex` instead of `charindex`? I tried using `charindex` in your query just to see if it would work but SQL Fiddle returns an error when I try `select myval,case when charindex('_',myval) then
substring(myval,1,patindex('%[_]%',myval)-1) else myval end from t` (I was trying to use `charindex` bit by bit so I left the second `patindex` in for now...)

Comment: hmm.. pls go through the [Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186323.aspx),[DOC1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188395.aspx)...

Comment: I saw that before; hence my question. They both return the starting position of the string / pattern searched for. As far as I can see, they both should work. You are using patindex because you look for a pattern, but why doesn't `charindex('_', ...)` work? I fail to see that.

Answer (score 3):

```
select SUBSTRING(MyValue,CHARINDEX('_',MyValue)+1,LEN(MyValue)) from DB.Table
```

Comment: This does the exact opposite of what I want -> it returns everything AFTER `_` (if there is a `_`), not what is before :)

Comment: Still fails, but thanks for the effort! I can use @861051069712110711711's solution though :-)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
select
    case when MyValue is null then '' --if null return empty string
    when charindex('_', MyValue) > 0 then
        left(MyValue, charindex('_', MyValue)-1)
    else
        MyValue --Return the field value if an underscore is not present
    end as Result

from
  DB.Table
```

Comment: Either needs an `else` before `case when charindex(...` and another `end` after `else MyValue end`, or the better option would be `case when MyValue is null then '' when charindex('_'....` (i.e. remove the second `case`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going with @861051069712110711711's solution but only because MyValue is never null. However, yours is basically the same but I can only accept 1 answer. Very much appreciated though!

Answer (score 1):

Try out this one:

```
  declare @st varchar(20)
set @st ='4365463_CORRU'    
select @st, SUBSTRING(@st,CHARINDEX('_',@st)-LEN(@st),LEN(@st))
```

Comment: This does the exact opposite of what I want -> it returns everything AFTER `_` (if there is a `_`), not what is before :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this .

```
declare @t table (myvalue varchar(50))

insert into @t
values ( '123'),('122_DELETED'),('45670'),('42425'),('43_NO_VIEW'),('4365463_CORRUPT'),('53'),('4335_NO_VIEW_ALLOWED')


select * from @t

;With  cte as
(
    select CHARINDEX( '_', myvalue)+1 d , myvalue from @t
)
select SUBSTRING(myvalue,d,LEN(myvalue) ) from cte
```